# Programmatically reinitializing a UIView causes it to not update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I have a UIViewController which has a small scrollable window, in which I put a custom UIView called "TreeView".  TreeView is blank, but has child classes of specific trees.  In my code, in viewDidLoad, I am doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    CGRect treeFrame = self.treeView.frame;
    NSLog(@"passing tree frame of origin %f %f, size: %f, %f", treeFrame.origin.x, treeFrame.origin.y, treeFrame.size.height, treeFrame.size.width);
    self.treeView = [[GelbMotiveView alloc] initWithFrame:treeFrame];
}
```

Then, in my test child, I load it's .xib file (successfully) and see that UIViews and subviews are added to the child.  However, these views are never rendered, even if I call  setNeedsDisplay.  Instead, the original TreeView is rendered (I gave it a red background so I would know for sure).  I can put a break point in drawRect in the test child class and it's never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I just doing something completely weird?  Should subclasses of UIView not have their own subclasses?  Is there a better way to programmatically swap out a small section of a UIViewController's screen? My intent is for the children of TreeView to render a tree/graph and make it intractable (buttons, etc, for nodes).  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that `treeView` is an `IBOutlet` and loaded from a nib?

If that is the case, the mistake you are making is reinitializing that pointer with `initWithFrame:` which wipes out your reference to the original view and creates a new one that isn't hooked up to anything. You can change the frame and change properties on it but you shouldn't initialize it again.